# Однородные члены или 2 предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

"К счастью, Печорин был погружен в раздумья, * и, кажется, вовсе не торопился в дорогу".
Запятая со звездочкой отделяет два предложения, как я понимаю. Но почему это не однородные сказуемые? "Печорин" — подлежащее; что о нем говорится? — что погружен в раздумья и то, что  не торопился в дорогу.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

К счастью, **Печорин был погружен в раздумья** **и**, кажется, **вовсе не торопился** в дорогу.

Это действительно однородные сказуемые, обособлено вводное слова ***кажется***.

Comment: Спасибо! Значит в ответах к упр. у Розенталя опечатка.

Comment: Можете дать ссылку на ответы?

Comment: А какие ссылки? Вы сомневаетесь в однородности сказуемых? У них разная грамматическая форма, но это не мешает их однородности. Здесь даже при большом желании трудно отыскать два предложения, так как по смыслу сказуемые близки и описывают одну ситуацию. Они полностью подходят под описание однородных членов (грамматическая и семантическая однородность). Грамматическая однородность подразумевает, что они относятся к одному подлежащему.

Comment: Полное предложение выглядит так: _К счастью, Печорин был погружен в задумчивость, глядя на синие зубцы Кавказа, и, кажется, вовсе не торопился в дорогу._ http://pedlib.ru/Books/4/0038/4_0038-213.shtml Запятая, думаю, "осталась" от деепричастного оборота.